# swap not working with function as parameter

Tags: c++, vector, stl, allocator

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> func()
{
    vector<int> a(3,100);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> b(2,300);
    //b.swap(func());   /* why is this not working? */
    func().swap(b);  /* and why is this working? */
    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, `b.swap(func())` is not compiling. It gives an error:

> no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::swap(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_vector.h:929: note: candidates are: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::swap(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]

But, when written as `func().swap(b)`, it compiles.

What exactly is the difference between them?

Comment: Your function returns a _rvalue_, so the 1st version cannot work.

Comment: I think this is a valid question - why downvote?

Answer (score 6):

`func()` returns a temporary object (an rvalue).

[`std::vector::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) takes a non-const `vector&` reference as input:

```
void swap( vector& other );
```

A temp object cannot be bound to a non-const reference (it can to a const reference).  That is why `b.swap(func());` does not compile.

Methods can be called on a temp object before it goes out of scope, and a named variable (an lvalue) can be bound to a non-const reference. That is why `func().swap(b)` compiles.